# How to create the column words as row and give each word weight and file number in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matrix

I have a large amount of data in a file that I viewed in the Pandas library. The file has three important columns, a column containing words represented by numbers, a column containing the file numbers in which each word appeared, and a column containing a weight for each word. There are repeated words that have appeared in many files that are expressed by a number in the column containing file numbers. Destination:

[image]

Now what I want is to make the column of words a row so that each word becomes in a column and put the column of file numbers so that the word appears in which file number appeared and put the weight under the word
As it is shown in the picture:

[image]

I tried to use transpose and csv library and tried to take every word and put it inside the single list but I can't reach a solution.

So if there is any solution with pandas or others libraries tell me, please.

Thank you all for your help my experience is little and I want to learn from you

Comment: It looks like a pivot table to me, perhaps with a custom aggfunc.  If you were to post your data itself, instead of a picture of it, I'd try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. Let me know:
Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'word_a', 100],
                   [1, 'word_b', 200],
                   [1, 'word_c', 300],
                   [2, 'word_d', 400],
                   [2, 'word_e', 500],
                   [3, 'word_f', 600],
                   [3, 'word_g', 700],
                   [3, 'word_h', 800],],
                   columns=['fileNum', 'WordID', 'Weight'])
```

[image]

Pivot the dataframe:

```
df.pivot(index='fileNum', columns='WordID', values='Weight')
```

[image]